# How to write Unit Testing for EJB Lookup methods

Tags: mocking, ejb-3.0, junit4

hi am new in writing unit test cases using junit & mocking for jee, can u pls explain one example of writing test cases for ejb lookup method.

my error:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.jmp.cmp.system.JxServiceLocator

Comment: What did you try so far? You should post the code that caused that error.

Comment: can u pls provide me an example for writing unit test case of ejb lookup()